# How to to fix nginx listening externally on port 8080 and internally on port 80?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, system-administration

Nginx started and listening on port 80 but it can only be accesed externally on port 8080.
`curl 0:80` works fine with a 200 response and `curl 0:80` reponds with connection refused but externally, `curl example.com:80` is stuck and never responds
while curl `example.com:8080` responds with 200
Port 80 is allowed on ufw

Initially I forwarded port 80 to 8080 before the issue started, then I removed the port forwarding configuration setting from `/etc/ufw/before.rules` yet the issue still persisted.
I stopped my nginx server and it stopped, then I started the server again and the issue started.
My nginx is configured to run on port 80, `netstat -lpn` confirms that nginx is running on port 80.
But it is not responding externally on port 80 but port 8080
I also tried `nc -z 0 80 ; echo $?` and it returned 0.
But `nc -z 8080 ; echo $?` is returning 1 but I can't find the processes listening on port 8080.
I've tried `ps aux` too.

Comment: Is there a router or firewall between the server with Nginx running on port 80, and the server you are running `curl` from?

Comment: No just ufw on which 80/tcp is allowed and I explained how I went about it there

Comment: What do you get when you run the command `ss -an  '( sport = 8000 )'` (`ss` is a tool similar to `netstat`, with slightly different options)

Comment: Just:
`Netid          State          Recv-Q          Send-Q                   Local Address:Port                   Peer Address:Port         Process `

Comment: Nothing for 8000 and 8080 but :80 is displaying
`Netid         State           Recv-Q          Send-Q                   Local Address:Port                   Peer Address:Port         Process         
tcp           LISTEN          0               511                            0.0.0.0:80                          0.0.0.0:*                            
tcp           LISTEN          0               511                               [::]:80                             [::]:*    `

Comment: One thing I found out is this, nginx is responding internally on port 80 and externally on port 8080.
My ufw confiiguration is okay, and port 8080 is not even allowed on my ufw
`sudo ufw status` has this:
`22/tcp              ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)`

Comment: Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. Systems administration questions are better directed to [sf] or perhaps [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by flushing the chains in the NAT table and removing sub chains

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo iptables --table nat --flush
sudo iptables --table nat --delete-chain
sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: This has been causing me issues for ages! Every port except 80 would work lol.